# Searching for a sentence in a file java

Tags: java, file, search

I am really stuck up with this. 
I am having an input file say input.txt.
content of input.txt is

```
  Using a musical analogy, hardware is like a musical instrument and software is like the notes played on that instrument.
```

Now I want to search the text

```
 like a musical instrument
```

How can I search the above content in input.txt in java. Any help???

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Sir actually I really dont know what I want to use for searching this kind of content in java.

Comment: You should really show some effort to solve the problem yourself, before asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the *String#contains()* method to search for substrings. Here, we will read each line in the file one by one, and check for a string match. If a match is found, we will stop reading the file and print *Match is found!*

```
package com.adi.search.string;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SearchString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputFileName = "input.txt";
        String matchString = "like a musical instrument";
        boolean matchFound = false;

        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFileName))) {

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                if(scanner.nextLine().contains(matchString)) {
                    matchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException exception) {

            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(matchFound)
            System.out.println("Match is found!");
        else
            System.out.println("Match not found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inorder to search a pattern in java, java provides contains() method in String. Try to use that, Following is the snippet of the code that serve the purpose,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("sat.txt"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String s = null;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(s.contains("like a musical instrument")) {
            System.out.println("String found");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("String not found");
}
```